# How do you count the number of items in a list in FileMaker

Tags: filemaker

I have a field in FileMaker that is populated by a checklist. How can I get a count of how many items were selected in the checklist for that field?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

Use the `ValueCount ( field )` function.